# Maximaze window from qt designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Every time i change something in .ui file from qt designer, then i compile with pyuic5 command.

Then i put `MainWindow.showMaximized()` instead of `MainWindow.show()` command.

Is there any way to do it from Qt Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;** No, it is not possible.

---

Qt Designer is used to:

- Configure the qproperties of QWidgets.
- Make connections between widgets.
- Edit some properties of the QActions.
- Create and modify qresource.

And in none of these possibilities does it involve method `showMaximized`.